# Using jq to put a result list into an enclosing object

Tags: json, jq

**Input**: The output from my current jq filters looks like

```
{
  "id1": {
    "version": 4,
    "lastModifier": "abc"
  }
}
{
  "id2": {
    "version": 3,
    "lastModifier": "def"
  }
}
{
  "id3": {
    "version": 8,
    "lastModifier": "abc"
  }
}
```

**Desired Output**: I just need to wrap this list in a object so I end up with

```
{
  "ref": {
      "id1": {
          "version": 4,
          "lastModifier": "abc"
      },
      "id2": {
          "version": 3,
          "lastModifier": "def"
      },
      "id3": {
          "version": 8,
          "lastModifier": "abc"
      }
   }
}
```

I don't want to merge anything from the input list into the output object, all the properties need to remain as-is, so piping to `add` doesn't work. Also tried wrapping my filters with `{ "ref": (` *filters* `)}` but that yields the same list with a "ref" wrapper for each object. Possibly `reduce` is what is needed but haven't been able to construct that appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-s` flag to read the stream into an array, the `add` it up and put it into your object:

```bash
jq -s '{ref: add}'
```

```json
{
  "ref": {
    "id1": {
      "version": 4,
      "lastModifier": "abc"
    },
    "id2": {
      "version": 3,
      "lastModifier": "def"
    },
    "id3": {
      "version": 8,
      "lastModifier": "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/u-s2E4OiEmC)

---

Of course, there is also a solution using `reduce`:

```bash
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $in ({}; .ref += $in)'
```

```json
{
  "ref": {
    "id1": {
      "version": 4,
      "lastModifier": "abc"
    },
    "id2": {
      "version": 3,
      "lastModifier": "def"
    },
    "id3": {
      "version": 8,
      "lastModifier": "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vtKZg_0Zapz)

Comment: I never remember `-s`, I had come up with `jq -n '{"ref": [inputs] | add }'` which works out to nearly the same thing.

Comment: I was trying to do it via a single instantiation of jq. Didn't think to have 2 instantiations each with different args. Thanks!

Comment: @GBC You can definitely do it with a single invocation of jq, but you'd need to reveal the first filter if you want us to help combinine the two. Generally speaking, wrapping your first filter with array brackets would have the same effect as using `-s` with a follow-up invocation, but there might be better ways depending on your first filter. So, for now, try `jq '[‌...] | {ref: add}'` (or even `jq '{ref: ([...] | add)}'`) with `...` being your first filter.

Comment: @pmf Both `jq '[...] | {ref: add}'` and `jq '{ref: [...] | add}'` gave the same result as a single invocation for my use case. Thanks again.